# How to fire a function on clicking by a dynamically added button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with a component that has a button to add a list of dynamic buttons. Each dynamic button has the onClick method to fire a function (sendOption) with an id parameter. **The problem is, the function "sendOption" is not firing after clicking on the added button.**

I also changed this:

```
<button onClick={this.sendOption(buttonId)}>
```

to this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.sendOption(buttonId)}>
```

but still, the onClick is not working. How can I solve this?

**Component:**

```
let buttonId = 0;

Class ButtonCreation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonsList: [],
        }
    }

    addButton = () => {
        buttonId += 1;

        this.setState({ 
             buttonsList: [...this.state.buttonsList, <button onClick={this.sendOption(buttonId)}>Send Option</button>]
        })
    }

    sendOption = (buttonId) => {
       console.log(buttonId)
    }

    render() {
       return(
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.addButton}>Add new Button</button>
            {this.state.buttonsList}
          </div>
       );
    }
}

export default ButtonCreation;
```

Comment: it's should work, look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-gould-d995j

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with click event binding :

Change this:

```
onClick={this.sendOption(buttonId)}
```

To :

```
onClick={() => this.sendOption(buttonId)}
```

> **NOTE :**
>
> on button click, it will not print right id with that button, but prints last
>   `buttonId` always, I have also solved that issue.Another issue with you code is when the user clicks on any, with this :
>
> `<button value={buttonId} onClick={(e) => this.sendOption(e.target.value)}>Send Option</button>`

---

You can run the code snippet and check :

```js
let buttonId = 0;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonsList: []
        }
    }

    addButton = () => {
        buttonId += 1;

        this.setState({ 
             buttonsList: [...this.state.buttonsList, <button value={buttonId} onClick={(e) => this.sendOption(e.target.value)}>Send Option</button>]
        })
    }
    
    sendOption = (buttonId) => {
       console.log(buttonId)
    }

    render() {
       return(
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.addButton}>Add Button </button>
              <br/><br/>
              {this.state.buttonsList}
            </div>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let buttonId = 0;
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    buttonsList: []
  };
 }

addButton = () => {
   buttonId += 1;

  this.setState({
    buttonsList: [
      ...this.state.buttonsList,
      <button id={buttonId} onClick={(e) => this.sendOption(e)}>Send Option</button>
    ]
  });
};

sendOption = e => {
  console.log(e.target.id);
};

render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addButton}>Add new Button</button>
        {this.state.buttonsList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-flower-7fm05?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for each button with each id:

use *target.id* for getting each button ID by click
use *key* for avoiding DOM key Problem

```
let buttonId = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [buttonsList, setbuttonsList] = useState([]);

  const addButton = () => {
    buttonId += 1;

    setbuttonsList(prevState => [
      ...prevState,
      <button
        key={buttonId}
        id={buttonId}
        onClick={event => sendOption(event, event.target.id)}
      >
        Send Option
      </button>
    ]);
  };

  const sendOption = (event, id) => {
    console.log(id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addButton}>Add new Button</button>
      {buttonsList}
    </div>
  );
}
```

code [https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-firefly-c7nrc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost solved by @Vivek.

But there are few points that I wanted to suggest you in your code.
You will get better idea by looking at the following code snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonsList: [],
      btnCounter: 0,
    }
  }

 addButton = () => { 
    // you can pass name, value for new button based on some value
    // you can also generate new id every time: const id = new Date().getTime();
    // use functional setState whenever update previous state
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
      btnCounter: prevState.btnCounter + 1,
      buttonsList: [...prevState.buttonsList, {
        id: prevState.btnCounter + 1,
        name: `Name${prevState.btnCounter + 1}`,
        value: `Send Option`
      }]
    }));
   // if possible add properties of button instead of directly adding element into state
  }

  sendOption = (buttonId) => {
    console.log(buttonId)
  }

  render() {
    const { buttonsList } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addButton}>Add new Button</button>
        {buttonsList && buttonsList.length > 0 && buttonsList.map((btn, i) => (
          <div key={btn.id}>
            <button
              name={btn.name}
              onClick={() => this.sendOption(btn.id)}
            >
              {btn.value}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```